# Nested forms in rails for existing objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

In my app, I have a page where I want admin users to be able to update a particular characteristic of my "Package" model, which belongs to both the "Order" model and the "Item" model. It's a little complicated, but I basically want to present in a table all of the Packages belonging to a given Item, ordered in a particular way (that's what my packages_for_log method below does), with two blanks for updating the weight of the item. All the updates should ideally be submitted at once, with a single submit button at the bottom of the page. I've attempted a whole bunch of solutions, and my current one is below, but gives this error when I visit the page in my server:

```
undefined method `actual_lbs' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007ff67df6c9c8>
```

The error's confusing to me, cause I was hoping that I was calling that method on the package instance, not a helper. Bit confused. At any rate, my code is below. The relevant section of the view:

```
<% form_for(@item) do |a| %>
  <% @item.packages_for_log.each do |p| %>
    <%= a.fields_for p do |i| %>
     <tr>
        <td><%= p.order.name %></td>
        <td><%= p.order.processed_notes %></td>
      <% if p.order.user %>
        <td><%= "#{p.order.user.name.first(3).upcase}-#{p.id}" %></td>
      <% else %>
        <td><%= p.order.id %></td>
      <% end %>
        <td>
          <%= i.text_field :actual_lbs %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= i.text_field :actual_oz %>
        </td>
          <%= i.hidden_field :true_weight, value: (i.actual_lbs + i.actual_oz/16) %>
     </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Relevant section of the package.rb model file:

```
 attr_accessible :order_id, :price, :true_weight, :actual_lbs, :actual_oz
 attr_accessor :actual_lbs, :actual_oz  # These two are virtual attributes for the above calc
```

And I added resources :packages to my routes file.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? It's important to me that I loop through to create a table based on "p" and then edit that same "p" object. Just not sure how to do it. Pretty new to Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:

```
<%= i.hidden_field :true_weight, value: (i.actual_lbs + i.actual_oz/16)
```

You need to put p.actual_lbs and p.actual_oz

EDIT: By the way, you probably need to move the true weight calculation to your controller action (CREATE action). I don't think :true_weight will get passed as you intended it to, using the above method.

Comment: Thanks! So I tried that edit, but I'm not sure what to put in the controller now. Since I'm submitting the Item, do I do "if @item.save" etc, and will that auto-nest the package saves? How does the controller know about the "p" variable to make the true_weight calculation? Thanks again!

Comment: Sasha, you should have access to the nested form information.. All you need to do is put figure out how the info is being sent in the params hash... probably something like params[:order][:actual_lbs].. check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html (section 2.3) ... also, once you know the params you will just do the calculation using the variables in the params, then assigning to item.true_weight before saving item